# No webpage was found for the web address: HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, nodemailer

I am sending the reset link(with JWT token)  to the registered users using nodemailer but when the user click on ***Reset Password*** then the error occurs(Given in title and image ).

**Here are my routes on frontend**:

```
   <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
    <Route path='contact' element={<Contact />} />
    <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
    <Route path='sendpasswordresetemail' element={<SendPasswordResetEmail />} />
    <Route path='api/user/reset/:id/:token' element={<ResetPassword />} />
    </Route>
```

**Routes on backend**

```
router.post('/register',UserController.userRegistration);
router.post('/login',UserController.userLogin);
router.post('/send-reset-password-email',UserController.sendUserPasswordResetEmail);
router.post('/reset/:id/:token',UserController.userPasswordReset);
```

**I am using the router on app.js like**

```
app.use('/api/user',web)
```

**Here is my code to generate link to reset password**

```
 static sendUserPasswordResetEmail = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { email } = req.body;
            if (email) {
                const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: email })
                if (user) {
                    const secret = user._id + process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY
                    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, secret, {
                        expiresIn: '30m'
                    });
                   
                    const link = `http://localhost:3000/api/user/reset/${user._id}/${token}`
                    // send email 
  await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

                    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
                    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                        host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
                        port: 587,
                        auth: {
                            user: 'guadalupe.harber@ethereal.email',
                            pass: 'qvt5fj9syFTXV61ZnQ'
                        }
                    
                    });
                    
                    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
                        from:"bernita.monahan@ethereal.email",
                        to: user.email,
                        subject: "Reset your password ",
                        html: `<a href=${link}>Click here</a> to reset password`
                    });
                    console.log(link)
                    return res.send({
                        "status": "success",
                        "message": "Email sent succsfully",
                        "info":info
                    })

                } else {
                    return res.send({
                        "status": "failed",
                        "message": "User doesn't exist"
                    })
                }
            } else {
                return res.send({
                    "status": "failed",
                    "message": "Email is required"
                })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }
```

*I am not getting any other error on both frontend and backend*

[image: Error Image]

Comment: This is a server error, your only showing frontend code. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: When I remove the dot(.) from the url then it starts to work but JWT token comes with dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging for a long time I finally found the problem. The 404 error was dute to the dot(.) in the url.
**Solutions:**

```
 const link = `http://localhost:3000/api/user/reset/${user._id}/${token}`.replaceAll('.','-');
```

But you should also replace the - with dot(.) before verifying the jwt token.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing the JWT in the URL. The JWT should be in the authorisation HTTP header

Comment: @Liam sometimes it comes as a redirection parameter from external system. I don't know how to deal with it. React Router v5 was working fine with dots in the URL. This is the issue for me, because I cannot change the external app I'm using to get the token... Too bad, new v6 makes me crazy with the changes...